# Remove rows with multiple duplicate columns from database table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to remove the last row because userid and friendwith column is duplicated.

```
friendshipid    userid  friendwith  friendshipstatus
183             24      102          4
151             24      52           2
155             24      66           2
179             24      66           2
```

thanks.

Comment: why don't you have unique key constraints, instead of trying to delete the duplicates

Comment: any logic why the last row??? why not the last but one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to keep the latest friendship id then do something like this

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table AS (SELECT * FROM table);
DELETE FROM table WHERE friendshipid NOT IN (SELECT friendshipid FROM (SELECT * FROM temp_table ORDER BY friendshipid DESC) as temp_table GROUP BY userid, friendwith);
DROP TABLE temp_table ;
```

Or if you want to keep the oldest friendship id then do something like this

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table AS (SELECT * FROM table);
DELETE FROM table WHERE friendshipid NOT IN (SELECT friendshipid FROM (SELECT * FROM temp_table ORDER BY friendshipid ASC) as temp_table GROUP BY userid, friendwith);
DROP TABLE temp_table ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could delete all rows for which another row exists with the same `userid` and `friendswith`, but a lower `friendshipid`.  For example:

```
delete  dup
from    YourTable as dup
join    YourTable orig
on      orig.userid = dup.userid
        and orig.friendwith = dup.friendwith
        and orig.friendshipid < dup.friendshipid
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0718/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
select friendshipid  ,  userid  , friendwith  , friendshipstatus from table 
group by userid , friendwith
```